# El expression passing as value to another el expression

Tags: jsp, date, jstl

I am just asking is this expression is correct i get an error of Unterminated <sql:param tag while it is closed.

I just wanna know is this expression is correct.

```
<sql:param value="<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" dateStyle="full"/>"
```

and this does not work why

```
<fmt:parseDate var="date"  value="${param.month}, ${param.day}, ${param.year}" type="DATE"
 pattern="dd/mm/yyyy" />
```

Comment: You cannot nest JSP tags like that, the same way you can't use an XML tag in the attribute of another tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSPX has to be well-formed XML. Nesting XML-flavored tags like that is indeed invalid.

Just make use of the `var` attribute of [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) tag to create a scoped variable which you in turn can refer in another tag.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" dateStyle="full" var="formattedDate" />
<sql:param value="${formattedDate}" />
```

---

As to your `<fmt:parseDate>` attempt, it failed because the pattern which you specified in `value` attribute doesn't match the pattern which you specified in `pattern` attribute. You're basically specifying the pattern `MM, dd, yyyy` in the value while the pattern expects `dd/mm/yyyy`. Also note that `mm` stands for minutes, not months. You need `MM` for months.

Just make sure that they match.

```
<fmt:parseDate var="date" value="${param.month}/${param.day}/${param.year}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
```

See also [the `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for detail on pattern characters.